# Actionscript 3.0 KEY_DOWN only working for certain keys

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events

So I'm new to Actionscript 3, and I'm trying to make a piano that corresponds to the keyboard keys A through K. I wrote some script (shown below) to check for KEY_DOWN events, and it doesn't work for most of the lowercase letters. All of the uppercase letters, numbers, and other keys correctly trace and reset aPlay, but of the lowercase letters, only w,d,x u, and g seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
//aKey is an object defined outside the script that works fine.
stop();

var aPlay:int = 1;
aKey.alpha = 0.1*aPlay;

this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, playPiano);
this.stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onUpdate );

function playPiano(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    //if(e.keyCode == 65)//Commented out for now
        aPlay = 5;

    trace(e.keyCode);//Debug
}

function _onUpdate( e:Event ):void
{
    aKey.alpha = 0.2*aPlay;

    if (aPlay > 1){
        aPlay--;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't check for lowercase/uppercase, you check for keycodes, which are equal to uppercase letters, and you can also check shift state of the `KeyboardEvent` to determine if the letter was uppercase.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but thanks anyway. Even when I'm just tracing whatever key was pressed, most of the letters don't respond unless I'm holding down shift. This is really bizarre...

Comment: Are you testing in the IDE? Have you disabled the keyboard shortcuts from the Control menu?

Comment: That was it, I didn't disable keyboard shortcuts! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class Test_Keyboard extends Sprite{
    public function Test_Keyboard() {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, trEvent)
    }

    private function trEvent(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        trace(event.keyCode, event.shiftKey, event.charCode)

        switch (event.charCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.A:
                trace("A")
                break;
            case 97: 
                trace("a")
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Did not found table of charCode, just traced it.